# (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) Cannot install python3-pip, error message (code 1) appear

Tags: python, pip

(Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) Cannot install python3-pip, error message (code 1) appear

First of all, I get the ubuntu from here and run in usb drive:
https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Secondly, I know that the python3/pip is in universal repository, so that I enable universal here:
[enable universal repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYIwW.png)

Thirdly, I follow the page here that teach you how to install pip for python3 by:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-22.04/

sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip

The problem happened to "sudo apt install python3-pip", after I execute this line, the screen goes black showing ubuntu logo and back to the Terminal and continue installation.
But then it comes out an error message: [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpEv6.jpg)
and few seconds later the whole Ubuntu system hang and I need to hard reboot the computer.

I try to google and get the intruction from this page but helpless:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-22.04/

Can somebody help to try the above steps and tell me which step goes wrong and how to fix it? Thank you so much.

Will the error cause by the ubuntu server?

Comment: `apt install` won't crash the entire machine, no matter what it does. Something's wrong with your computer. What you describe sounds like an overheated CPU that just stops working. Stuck fan perhaps?

Comment: Appreciate to your response. But I try the same steps on another computer and it comes the same result. The another one got hang and need hard reboot with the same error code shown on the picture above:   E:sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Are you running off the usb drive? More than likely the drive lost connection to the computer. Might be a bad drive.

Comment: Yes. I run the Ubuntu on the usb drive. Actually I do the same before and nothing goes wrong. But I do have this error message this time.

Comment: @scrappedcola I tried to create ubuntu on another usb drive and run the same code (https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-22.04/) but it fails too.

Actually there are not much steps I did
1) Load into the ubuntu OS and enable universe repository
2) open Terminal , type "sudo apt update"
3) then type "sudo apt install python3-pip"

And then i got the error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpEv6.jpg
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
a few seconds later, the OS hang and hard reboot is needed. 

Can somebody try the above step and see what happen

Comment: Have you tried asking on the Ubuntu Stackexchange askubuntu? This is kind of off topic for stackoverflow as it's not a programming question per say.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder! I switch to there.